# Proof of the Compactness theorem (Exercise)

Tags: logic

I would like some help to evaluate this proof that I have written for the compactness theorem. I have just started learning mathematical logic (my background is in philosophy) so I am not comfortable yet with using symbols. Hence, my proof is very informal. Now, the exercise states the following:

"*Assume that every finite subset of S is satisfiable. Show that the
same is true of at least for one of the sets $S \cup α$ and $S \cup ¬α$. (This is
part of the proof of the compactness theorem.) Suggestion: If not,
then the union between $S_1$ and α ,and the union $S_2$ $\cup$ $¬α$ are unsatisfiable for some finite $S_1$ ⊆ S and $S_2$ ⊆ S.*"

Now, my argument is the following. I am not using the tips that the exercise gives regarding the union. I am following another route:

1. We know that every subset of S is satisfiable.
2. So, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are a subset of S, they must be satisfiable.
3. If not, take $S_3$ and $S_4$ respectively members of $S_1$ and $S_2$. Either
   they are satisfiable, or take S5 and S6, respectively members of $S_3$
   and $S_4$. And so on.
4. At some points, you find a set $S_n$ {$\phi$} or $S_n + 1$ {$¬\phi$} that are singlets.

Now, either $S_n$ $\cup$ {$\alpha$} is satisfiable or $S_n + 1$ $\cup$ {$¬ \alpha$} is satisfiable. If not, you can go back another step, and find that $S_n$ is not satisfiable. But it seems to me absurd, because if no singlet of a set S of formulas is satisfiable, then also no subset which is made of the singlet plus another formula can be satisfiable, and this would contradict our initial assumption. Also, it seems to me that every singlet in a set of formulas is satisfiable, because you can always find a truth-assignment v($\phi$) such that v($\phi$) = T.

Another proof I tought about is that you can always take a singlet {$\phi$} that is satisfiable and add a formula {a} or {-a} and keep the result satisfiable. You can then arrive to S, and if you still add a term such that either one of "S $\cup$ α" or  "S $\cup$ ¬α" is satisfiable, the new set remains satisfiable.

I guess this is not a very well done proof, but hoped for some suggestions on how to improve it (if it makes any sense at all), correct it, and in general how to get better in proving stuff.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: “We know that every subset of $S$ is satisfiable”. No, you know that every *finite* subset of $S$ is satisfiable. If you knew every subset of $S$ were satisfiable, you’d be done already. In general the fact that the word “finite” doesn’t appear anywhere in your answer is a huge red flag.

Comment: (On a side note, your statement that any singleton is satisfiable is not correct. e.g. any set of the form $\{\varphi\land\lnot\varphi\}$ is not satisfiable.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!